# How to calculate loss without updating model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

To my understanding, below code will calculate loss and update parameters in the model at the same time.

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
```

so how to calculate loss without updating model?

```
_, c1 = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
_, c2 = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
```

For example, `c1 != c2` since the first line have updated the model.

### UPDATE1

I have tried below code, just run without `optimizer`

```
c1 = sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
c2 = sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
```

but c1 is still not equal to c2

### UPDATE2

a dropout layer in my model causes the diff of c1 and c2 in my `UPDATE1`

Comment: Don't use `_, c1` , just use `c1`

Comment: @Akhilesh updated , sorry for the typo

Comment: @Akhilesh Actually, it should be either `c1,` (with a comma) or `c1` (without the comma) but removing the brackets around `loss`.

Comment: Without the comma. `c1 = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
c2 = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x:x, y:y})`

write in this way.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are checking equality anyway, but unless there are other variables involved (e.g. a stateful recurrent model), running twice the same operation should give you the same result. I've seen minor differences sometimes with GPU, but running `np.allclose(c1, c2)` should be `True`.

Comment: If only `loss` is operated, the weights will not be updated, like @jdehesa says. Is there some stochastic operations, like dropout, in your model? Is `c1` very different from `c2`?

Comment: @Seven yes... it's a dropout layer in my model, so it's the reason? and c1 is not very diff from c2

Comment: @YuwenYan, definitely!!! dropout selects the random neurons from the network and calculates the loss as per the selected neurons. If you want to cross verify, you can use `seed` in the `dropout()`.

Comment: so... try to turn off the dropout and see if you can get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the loss without updating the model, simply run the `loss` operation, without the `optimizer` operation.

```
c = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
```

Note that when you run `sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})` you get the loss value *before* applying the updates, so running:

```
_, c1 = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
c2 = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x:x, y:y})
```

Will still yield different values of `c1` and `c2`, since `c2` is the loss value *after* updating the model.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I just updated my question for your answer