# Test accuracy keeps changing for the same data set

Tags: tensorflow

I'm importing a pre-trained model and using it to classify some data. Is it normal that the predicted values/ final accuracy keeps changing every time I run the model for the same data set?

I printed the softmax values of the final layer as well. The probabilities keep changing.

Comment: No it should not during testing.

Comment: Actually probabilities can change a little on GPU (ie, tf.reduce_sum is non-deterministic because of CuDNN atomics) but usually not enough to change the actual value predicted. Does your pipeline have any randomness? (ie, randomshufflequeue)

Comment: I shuffled the data while training, but nothing while testing. I've imported the model as is. It's a Conv -> LSTM architecture, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encounter the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216094/how-to-calculate-loss-without-updating-model-in-tensorflow) recently, and finally I found the root cause is a dropout layer in my model, hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense! I have 2 dropout layers in the model. They helped increase performance though. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: this is how it works, if you need to produce consistent results, just don't use such layers in your model, which will also affect the performance of your model. @AnnaR